# What does the Bob say? (clojure version)

Tags: beginner, clojure

I'm doing the exercices from [clojureacademy](https://clojurecademy.com/).
Here are the instructions for this one.

> Bob is a lackadaisical teenager. In conversation, his responses are very limited.
>
> - Returns "Whatever." if given phrase is one of the following inputs:
>
>   - "Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to."
>   - "Let's go make out behind the gym!"
>   - "It's OK if you don't want to go to the DMV."
>   - "Ending with ? means a question."
>   - "1, 2, 3"
> - Returns "Woah, chill out!" if given phrase is one of the following inputs:
>
>   - "WATCH OUT!"
>   - "WHAT THE HELL WERE YOU THINKING?"
>   - "ZOMG THE %^*@#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!"
>   - "1, 2, 3 GO!"
>   - "I HATE YOU"
> - Returns "Sure." if given phrase is one of the following inputs:
>
>   - "Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?"
>   - "4?"
> - Returns "Fine. Be that way!" if given phrase is one of the following inputs:
>
>   - ""
>   - " "

Here is my code in `src/ex1_bob/core.clj`:

```
(ns ex1-bob.core
  (:gen-class))

; responses
; =======================
(def whatever "Whatever.")
(def chill-out "Woah, chill out!")
(def sure "Sure.")
(def fine "Fine. Be that way!")

; triggers
; =======================
(def sure-triggers
  ["Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?" "4?"])
(def whatever-triggers
  ["Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to."
   "Let's go make out behind the gym!"
   "It's OK if you don't want to go to the DMV."
   "Ending with ? means a question."
   "1, 2, 3"])
(def chill-out-triggers
  ["WATCH OUT!"
   "WHAT THE HELL WERE YOU THINKING?"
   "ZOMG THE %^*@#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!"
   "1, 2, 3 GO!"
   "I HATE YOU"])



(defn has-phrase
  "return `true` if the given phrase is found in the collection, `false` otherwise"
  [phrase coll] 
  (if (some #(= phrase %) coll)
    true
    false))

(defn response-for
  "return `true` if the given phrase is found in the collection, `false` otherwise"
  [phrase]
    (cond 
      (has-phrase phrase whatever-triggers)  whatever
      (has-phrase phrase chill-out-triggers) chill-out
      (has-phrase phrase sure-triggers)      sure
      (= (clojure.string/trim phrase) "")    fine))
```

I also wrote some tests in `test/ex1_bob/core_test.clj`:

```
(ns ex1-bob.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [ex1-bob.core :refer :all]))

; This does not work because `is` is a macro, and it seems it does not like to
; be used in a `map` or with `comp`.
;
; (deftest non-working-response-for-chill-out-triggers
;   (doall (map (comp is #(= % chill-out) response-for) chill-out-triggers)))

(deftest response-for-chill-out-triggers
  (is (every? #(= % chill-out) (map response-for chill-out-triggers))))

(deftest response-for-whatever-triggers
  (is (every? #(= % whatever) (map response-for whatever-triggers))))

(deftest response-for-sure-triggers
  (is (every? #(= % sure) (map response-for sure-triggers))))

(deftest response-for-empty-string
  (is (every? #(= % fine) (map response-for [""]))))
```

Two things make me a bit unhappy about this code:

- the `has-phrase` function seems a bit silly. Do I really have to write a function to return `true`/`false` if an element is found in a collection? I feel that there must be a function that does this already
- I first wrote my unit test with:

  ```
  (deftest non-working-response-for-chill-out-triggers
    (doall (map (comp is #(= % chill-out) response-for) chill-out-triggers)))
  ```

  The idea is to have one assertion for each item, which I assumed would give me a better error message in case of a failure (because I know which item failed). But it seems that `is` is a macro and somehow, the interpreter doesn't like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, working top-down, your triggers at the top should be in sets (`#{}`), not vectors (you'll see why a little farther down):

```
(def sure-triggers
  #{"Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?"
    "4?"})

(def whatever-triggers
  #{"Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to."
    "Let's go make out behind the gym!"
    "It's OK if you don't want to go to the DMV."
    "Ending with ? means a question."
    "1, 2, 3"})

(def chill-out-triggers
  #{"WATCH OUT!"
    "WHAT THE HELL WERE YOU THINKING?"
    "ZOMG THE %^*@#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!"
    "1, 2, 3 GO!"
    "I HATE YOU"})
```

---

`has-phrase` has a couple things that can be improved:

- Clojure ends predicates with a `?` by convention. I'd rename it to `has-phrase?`.
- `some` already returns a truthy/falsey value. `(if pred? true false)` is unnecessary.

Just reduce it to:

```
(defn has-phrase?
  "Return whether or not the given phrase is found in the collection"
  [phrase coll]
  (some #(= phrase %) coll))
```

BUT, now that you're using sets instead of vectors, this whole function is unnecessary:

```
(whatever-triggers "1, 2, 3")
=> "1, 2, 3" ; Truthy

(whatever-triggers "Not in the set")
=> nil
```

Sets themselves can be used as functions. If the item is in the set, they return the item back (a truthy result), else they return `nil` (falsey). This will also be much faster, since now you don't need to have `some` iterate potentially the entire vector (although obviously speed isn't a factor here). This changes `reponse-for` to:

```
(defn response-for
  "return `true` if the given phrase is found in the collection, `false` otherwise"
  [phrase]
  (cond
    (whatever-triggers phrase) whatever
    (chill-out-triggers phrase) chill-out
    (sure-triggers phrase) sure
    (= (clojure.string/trim phrase) "") fine))
```

---

This could be changed using some `some` trickery. `some` returns the first truthy value returned by its predicate. If you pass it pairs of `[trigger-set response]`, you can iterate over the the pairs to find the first one that satisfies it, then return the response:

```
(defn response-for2 [phrase]
  (some (fn [[trigger-set response]]
          (when (trigger-set phrase)
            response))

        [[sure-triggers sure]
         [chill-out-triggers chill-out]
         [whatever-triggers whatever]
         [#{"" " "} fine]]))
```

Now, in this particular example, I wouldn't recommend doing this. It's not as clear as what you already had. I have used `(some #(when ...))` before though, and it works great in some cases. I just thought I'd show you it here in case you run into a similar problem where this can be applied.

I'm sure something could be done using a map mapping triggers to responses, but I just did another Clojure review, and my brain's tapped out.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't open the link to the question site. But "Returns [X] if given phrase is one of the following inputs", to me, does not mean it only returns that for that inputs.
It also doesn't say you should return `nil` otherwise.

If we take the listed inputs to be test cases; then baking them in the implementation is not good.

I understand the cases to be as such:
- blank (nothing but whitespace)
- question (ends with `\?`, as hinted in example)
- shouting (all letters are uppercase)
- anyhing else

Comment: Oh I had not thought about that. Now that you say it, it seems kind of obvious that this is probably the right thing to do...